# Why does this code memory leak when adding `bracketOnError`?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, conduit

First, I appologize for not having a minimal example (I can attempt to construct one, but for now I have a "before and after" example):

First the "after" which has the memory leak:

```
protoReceiver :: RIO FdsEnv ()
protoReceiver = do
  logItS Info ["Entering FarmPCMessage protoReceiver"]
  tMap <- liftIO $ newThreadMap
  fdsEnv <- ask
  let lgr = fdsLogger fdsEnv
  loopBody <- pure $ bracketOnError
    (runResourceT $ protoServe fdsEnv tMap readFarmPCMessage)
    (\(_,w) -> do
      logLogItS Debug lgr ["Entering cleanup for protoReceiver"]
      )
    (\(server,_) -> do
      logLogItS Debug lgr ["Entering FarmPCMessage protoReceiver bracket"]
      server
        .| mapMC (liftIO . traverse_ (persistFarmEntry fdsEnv))
        .| mapMC ((logLogIt Info lgr) . pure)
        .| sinkUnits & runConduitRes
      )
  liftIO loopBody
```

Here's the "before" code, which does not memory leak:

```hs
protoReceiver :: RIO FdsEnv ()
protoReceiver = do
  logItS Info ["Entering FarmPCMessage protoReceiver"]
  tMap <- liftIO $ newThreadMap
  fdsEnv <- ask
  let lgr = fdsLogger fdsEnv

  (dmgrProtoServe, tcpWorker) <- liftIO $ runResourceT
    $ protoServe fdsEnv tMap readFarmPCMessage
  liftIO $ runResourceT $ dmgrProtoServe
    .| mapMC (liftIO . traverse_ (persistFarmEntry fdsEnv))
    .| mapMC ((logLogIt Info lgr) . pure)
    .| sinkUnits & runConduit
```

I did some profiling of the leak, though I'm not sure if it is particularly helpful (any suggestions on better profiling charts appreciated):

[image: profiling RTS with -hc]
[image: profiling RTS with -hd]

Comment: The only hypothesis that occurs to me is that the `server` value is retained longer than it should because it must be passed to the exception handler in case of error. I would try the hack/experiment of only directly returning `w` from the allocation action, and passing the `server` value to the body of the loop using an `MVar` instead.

Comment: @danidiaz  It looks like your intuition was correct, that did indeed fix the leak. But as you said, it does feel a bit hacky. Happy to keep it for now, but would be good to understand this more deeply.

Comment: This blog post might be related to the current problem: https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2016/09/sharing-conduit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a variant of the classic leak scenario in which we retain a reference to the head of a lazy list while it's being consumed:

```
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let xs = [1..]
    traverse_ print xs 
    traverse_ print xs -- commenting this statement solves the leak
```

Here, the conduit `Source` is working as a "lazy list" of sorts. We need to retain a reference to the original source value (`server`) even as we consume it, because it must be passed to the exception handler in case of error. And yet the exception handler doesn't seem to make use of it.

The solution is to cut that reference as soon as the main computation we pass to `bracketOnError` gets hold of the value. We can use an `MVar` for that purpose. Not because of its synchronization abilities, but because it's a mutable reference that can be "left empty".

The allocation action, instead of returning a `(Source m r, a)` value, could return an `(MVar (Source m r), a)` value instead. Then, the main computation would perfrom a `takeMVar` to get hold of the conduit source. Once we start consuming the source, the original value will be garbage collected because there won't remain any more references to it.

Here is the working code the OP used after following these suggestions:

```
protoReceiver :: RIO FdsEnv ()
protoReceiver = retryForever $ do
  logItS Info ["Entering FarmPCMessage protoReceiver"]
  tMap <- liftIO $ newThreadMap
  fdsEnv <- ask
  let lgr = fdsLogger fdsEnv
  loopBody <- pure $ bracket
    (runResourceT $ do
      swTup <- protoServe fdsEnv tMap readFarmPCMessage
      serverMVar <- newMVar $ fst swTup
      pure (serverMVar, snd $! swTup)
      )
    (\(_, worker) -> do
      logLogItS Debug lgr ["Entering cleanup for protoReceiver"]
      killChildThreads tMap
      cancel worker
      )
    (\(serverMVar, _) -> do
      logLogItS Debug lgr ["Entering FarmPCMessage protoReceiver bracket"]
      server <- takeMVar serverMVar
      logLogItS Debug lgr ["FarmPCMessage protoReceiver bracket: got server"]
      server
        .| mapMC (liftIO . traverse_ (persistFarmEntry fdsEnv))
        .| mapMC ((logLogIt Info lgr) . pure)
        .| sinkUnits & runConduitRes
      )
  liftIO $ retryForever $ loopBody
  where
    killChildThreads = liftIO . killThreadHierarchy
```

Comment: An interesting effect I noticed is that if I transition from using the takeMVar/putMVar approach as discussed in comments, to doing the MVar allocation in the bracket as discussed here, I appear to get a deadlock - or at least, the conduit output is not shown - I'll look into it more. However, if I swap out `takeMVar` with `readMVar`, the memory leak is back! I assume this is because GHC is smart enough to know that if we use `readMVar`, it can safely retain the reference to the MVar-wrapped value: https://gist.github.com/bbarker/6cd3c9fe8dbbcb63ad21ec4fda80e70d

Comment: @bbarker In the linked snippet, your are putting both the `server` and `w` values inside the `MVar`. This will create a deadlock when the exception handler is invoked, because by then the `MVar` will be empty! It's better to only put `server` in the `MVar` (that is, return an `MVar` in a tuple, instead of a tuple inside an `MVar`). That way the exception handler won't need to invoke `takeMVar`, it will have the `w` directly at hand.

Comment: oh right, of course. When I updated this (see updated gist link above) to take this suggestion into account, it seems it is back to leaking again). I suppose, as the article pointed out, this can be very finicky stuff. I [commented](https://gist.github.com/bbarker/6cd3c9fe8dbbcb63ad21ec4fda80e70d#gistcomment-3467478) with an alternative I may go with for now that doesn't leak nor does it use MVars, but on the negative side, also doesn't have a finalizer for the creation of the Conduit, currently. Still, it seems fairly resilient in my tests.

Comment: @bbarker You should perform an explicit pattern match against the result of `protoServe`, rather than depending on `fst` and `snd` to extract the components. The reason is that a reference to the tuple—and therefore to the conduit source— is hiding behind the `snd swTup` thunk. Laziness is tricky.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. I ended up just using `$!` for this purpose. I took the liberty to include my working code in your answer, for completeness.